# i created a table but the below error came . I don't know the reason

Tags: mysql, wampserver

```
create table Grant(GrantID int not null,GrantName varchar(255),EmpID int,amount int,primary key(GrantID),foreign key(EmpID) references Employee(EmpID));
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Grant(GrantID int not null,GrantName varchar(255),EmpID int,amount int,primary k' at line 1

why's this?? my code is correct right??

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your query:

. You are using `Grant` as your table name, which is a reserve word you cannot use it. So change the name of the table

. Check this line:

```
foreign key(EmpID) references Employee(EmpID));
```

before running the above query, make sure that the `Employee` table with the column `EmpID` is already there.

Make above changes and try again.